# Android Webservice SOAP

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I'm calling soap webservice in android app. its working fine and getting the response in SOAP object. I don't know what to do after that. I'm searching for tutorial but I didnt find any. I'm really very fed up. I need to parse the reponse. Can anybody please help me in this case.

```
    filter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
   //sign_up.setImageResource(R.drawable.signuphover);
    //Intent i = new Intent();
          //i.setClassName("com.android.istock","com.android.istock.signup");
          //startActivity(i);
    int type=0;
    int PageNo=1;
    int PageSize=10;

      SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
      request.addProperty("pStrType", type);
      request.addProperty("pIntPageNo", PageNo);
      request.addProperty("pIntPageSize", PageSize);
      //Log.v(LOG_TAG," value:="+name);
      //Log.v(LOG_TAG," value:="+pass);
      SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
      new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
      envelope.dotNet = true;
      envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
      AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
      try
      {
      androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
      SoapObject resultstring = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

Comment: pls reply anybody.. its urgent

Comment: Have you looked at this? [HelloAndroid Tutorials:using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data ](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data)

Comment: I've created a - proof-of-concept - SOAP client, please watch it... :) http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/Home

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void allowAllSSL() {

        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection
                    .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) (new URL(
                    "https://sPublic/Client.asmx"))
                    .openConnection();
            connection.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
```

Call Close Method after getting your reponce..
Then it wil Works

```
public static void close() { connection.disconnect(); }
```

Comment: public static void close() {

  connection.disconnect();

 }
This is the clos method